# Why I can't get the attributes from the root element using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, root, jdom

Lets consider this xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root attribute="value">
    <element>myElement</element>
</root>
```

I'm trying to parse the file using JDOM to extract the attribute name and value from the root element.

This is the code I mad for this purpose :

```
public static org.jdom.Document document;
public static org.jdom.Element root;

SAXBuilder sxb = new SAXBuilder();
try
{
    document = sxb.build(new File("file.xml"));
    root = document.getRootElement();

    List myList = root.getAttributes();
    Iterator x = myList.iterator();
    while(x.hasNext())
    {
        Attribute myAttribute = (Attribute)x.next();
        System.out.println("name : " +  myAttribute.getName() + " & value : " + myAttribute.getValue());
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Everything works fine for this xml file. But when I use this file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rootElement PUBLIC "-//Project" "mydtd.dtd">
<root attribute="value">
    <element>myElement</element>
</root>
```

I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Do you think I should remove the DOCTYPE from the xml file before parsing it and past it after I finish the parsing.

Or there is something else I can do in this situation ?

Thanks

Comment: what's line cause this null pointer exception ?

Comment: where the exception is thrown? Please provide stack trace and mark the line that throws exception.

Comment: root = document.getRootElement();

Comment: @OpenMind: That line is throwing the exception for the reason I stated in my answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or there is something else I can do in this situation ?

Yes - never, ever do this:

```
catch(Exception e){}
```

This is not a problem with JDOM or attributes, this is a problem with your general exception handling.

It's likely that you're getting a `NullPointerException` because the XML file didn't parse properly, so the `document` field is `null`. But because you caught and ignored the exception, you get no meaningful error message.

Move the all of the code you currently have *after* the catch block, inside the try/catch block, and you'll get a more useful error report.

Comment: @OpenMind: Yes, I know, but you should be, because that's what's causing your error (the `NullPointerException`). You may think the exception handling is irrelevant here, but it's not.

Comment: @OpenMind: See the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: Don't swallow the exception from sxb.build; allow it to be thrown, or at least print it out somewhere.

Comment: Ok I edited the code and xml to be more specific and now I have `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\hello_world\mydtd.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: @OpenMind: OK, so there's your problem. Either put the DTD file there, or remove the DOCTYPE from the XML file.

Comment: And don't tell me to bring the dtd. °_°

Comment: http://www.jdom.org/docs/faq.html#a0350 : "How do I keep the DTD from loading? Even when I turn off validation the parser tries to load the DTD file."